# Notepad++ delete everything but the strings I searched for/or copy the strings

Tags: notepad++

I performed a search `<a href="(.*).website.com/">` I want to either copy every instance of it or delete everything else and then put them on separate lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try these steps:-

1. Use this short-cut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open find window
2. Click on Mark tab,
3. Place your regular expression and
4. Select Regular Expression radio button
5. Click Mark All button (Refer the screenshot)
   [image: Step1]
6. You see number of occurence popup, close the window.
7. Click on `Search Menu` **`-->`** `Bookmark` **`-->`** You will list of facilities which you can avail it (Example: **Cut**, **Copy** and **Remove** Bookmarked lines options). (Refer to the screenshot)
   [image: Step2]

Comment: What i did was copy bookmarked lines, delete everything, paste the bookmarked lines and then used find and replace to remove everything else. thnx